# jQuery - actual time of "slow", "fast" and "normal"

Tags: jquery, animation, time

I am trying to find the following answer for the following question?

What is the actual time taken for the jQuery parameters "slow", "fast" and "normal"?

Answer (score 21):

From [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/effects.js#L597);

```
speeds: {
    slow: 600,
    fast: 200,
    // Default speed
    _default: 400
},
```

These speeds are also [documented](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) in the jQuery API, so you can most likely count on them not changing.

> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of **200** and **600** milliseconds, respectively. If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the **default duration of 400 milliseconds** is used.

Answer (score 6):

slow is 600

fast is 200

default is 400